# iOS write a file to a common/shared space

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I'm using this code to write to the *sandbox* of my iOS app:

```
char *saves = "abcd";
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:saves length:4]; 
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile"];
[data writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
```

Is there a way to write a file to a common space (like in android /sdcard/), so another app can edit that file without making a copy first?

Comment: This article provides some suggestions: http://enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, iOS does have a common space like android. So your options are limited.

You can share files via iCloud but then both apps should be from the same developer. The same goes if you share data via the KeyChain, also it is only suitable for small piece of data.

Apple does provide a document sharing option, which allows app to register themselves to handle file types. The [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) helps you to present the document sharing view.